# Drag and Drop an object with pressed shift|control key before the drop

Tags: ruby, testing, selenium, drag-and-drop, watir-webdriver

I'm using watir-webdriver for automated testing.
We need tests drag and drop with pressed shift|control key before the drop.

I need realize:
1. click element 'a'
2. start drag
3. press shift|control
4. continue drag
5. drop to element 'b'

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

module Selenium
  module WebDriver
    class ActionBuilder

      def hold(timeout)
        @devices.merge!(:self => self) unless @devices[:self]
        @actions << [:self, :sleep, timeout]
        self
      end

    end # ActionBuilder
  end # WebDriver
end # Selenium


begin
  browser = Watir::Browser.new
  browser.goto my_page
  a = browser.div(id: "a")
  b = browser.div(id: "b")
  browser.driver.action.click_and_hold(a.wd).move_to(b.wd).hold(3).key_down(:shift).key_up(:shift).release.perform
  #browser.driver.action.click_and_hold(a.wd).move_to(b.wd).hold(3).send_keys(:shift).release.perform

ensure
  browser.close
end
```

or if need drug with pressed shiift (hold)

```
browser.driver.action.key_down(:shift).click_and_hold(a.wd).move_to(b.wd).key_up(:shift).release.perform
```

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop support is in the roadmap: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RoadMap

Answer (score 0):

Per the [0.6.11 documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Element), the `Element` class has 2 drag and drop methods: [`drag_and_drop_by`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Element#drag_and_drop_by-instance_method) and [`drag_and_drop_on`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Element#drag_and_drop_on-instance_method).

The rdoc example for [`drag_and_drop_on`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Element#drag_and_drop_on-instance_method) appears to be what you're trying to accomplish:

```
a = browser.div(:id => "draggable")
b = browser.div(:id => "droppable")
a.drag_and_drop_on b
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class DragAndDropConcept {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://jqueryui.com/droppable/");

    driver.switchTo().frame(0);    

    Actions obj = new Actions(driver);

    obj.clickAndHold(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='draggable']")))
    .moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='droppable']")))
    .release().build().perform();

    }
    }
```

Comment: Try this code. I think it is useful for u. I appreciated,vote up the answers If you are satisfy with my answer.